# Erro csrf token no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou recebendo o erro

> TokenMismatchException
>   in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

quando dou submit nas informações da view a seguir. Detalhe é que em todas as minhas views eu tenho o csrf_token por causa do blade template. Enfim, minha view é essa:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

    <h1>Funções do <b>{{$user->name}}</b></h1><br>

    <form action="{{url("/users/{$user->id}/roles/salva")}}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="col-md-4 control-label">Access Level</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
               <option name="role_id" value="6">Viewer</option>
               <option name="role_id" value="5">Manager</option>
               <option name="role_id" value="3">Admin</option>
           </select>    
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar Função</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="/users" method="get">   
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Voltar</button>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Não sei ainda se esse dropdown vai funcionar mas isso não importa por enquanto (eu acho)

**@csrf em forma de texto na view**

[image: ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve colocar dentro do seu formulário `@csrf`.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

    <h1>Funções do <b>{{$user->name}}</b></h1><br>

    <form action="{{url("/users/{$user->id}/roles/salva")}}" method="POST">
         @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="col-md-4 control-label">Access Level</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
               <option name="role_id" value="6">Viewer</option>
               <option name="role_id" value="5">Manager</option>
               <option name="role_id" value="3">Admin</option>
           </select>    
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar Função</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="/users" method="get">   
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Voltar</button>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Outra forma de declara o csrf é:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Fonte: [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf)

Comment: Eu tinha feito esse teste, mas quando eu abria a view ele executava em forma de texto. Tipo, aparecia escrito na tela @csrf. Mas vou tentar denovo

Comment: Existe outra forma de declarar o csrf, editei a pergunta e coloquei

Comment: ok, valeu vou tentar

Comment: Funcionou, valeu

Comment: Por favor marque a pergunta como respondida, apertando no "v" verde.

Comment: tem q esperar 10min